# terraform environments and updating a single resource

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform

I am using Terraform for continuous deployments of lambda functions. The lambda module creates the function and initial aliases [DEV,QA,PROD]. When a change is made the `source_code_hash` is updated and Terraform updates the code. The challenge is when I want to update the alias from DEV to QA it updates the entire stack. The code is below. Your help is appreciated.

```
$ cat main.tf

module "sample" {
  source           = "./lambda"
  name             = "sample"
  runtime          = "nodejs6.10"
  role             = "${aws_iam_role.iam_role_for_lambda.arn}"
  filename         = "../Archive.zip"
  source_code_hash = "${base64sha256(file("../Archive.zip"))}"
  source_dir       = "../sample"
  alias            = "${var.env_name}"
}

$ cat module/main.tf
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda" {
  filename         = "${var.filename}"
  function_name    = "${var.name}"
  role             = "${var.role}"
  handler          = "${var.name}.${var.handler}"
  runtime          = "${var.runtime}"
  source_code_hash = "${data.archive_file.lambda_zip.output_base64sha256}"
  publish          = "true"
}

resource "aws_lambda_alias" "lambda_alias" {
  count = "2"
  name  = "${element(var.alias, count.index)}"

  #name             = "${var.alias}"
  description      = "${var.name}"
  function_name    = "${aws_lambda_function.lambda.arn}"
  function_version = "${aws_lambda_function.lambda.version}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need different `tfvars` and `tfstate` files for different environments.

Suppose you use latest terraform version.

create an environment folder (for example, `env`) and set `<env>-backend.tf` and `<env>.tfvars` files for each environment

```
$ cat main.tf

terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.9.1"

  backend "s3" {
    encrypt = "true"
  }
}

$ cat env/dev-backend.tf

bucket = "terraform-<change-to-s3-global-unique-id>"

key = "terraform/dev/terraform.tfstate"

kms_key_id = "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"


$ cat env/dev.tfvars

env_name = dev
```

Do the same for qa and prod environments.

So you should be fine to run below commands to get same `lambda` tf codes work in different environments

```
rm -rf .terraform    
export env="dev"
terraform init -backend=true -backend-config=env/${env}-backend.tf
terraform plan -var-file=./env/${env}.tfvars
```

Comment: thanks for the response. The challenge is that for this use case the DEV,QA and PROD are in the same account. What I wound up doing was using Terraform to manage the lambda function code and update the aliases through the aws cli. Thanks again.

Comment: Not understand what you are talking about. Of course, the codes work within the same account, what do you worry about?